# how to validate dynamic text box values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks in advance.I have a popup window which has a dynamic text box fields.These textboxes will multiple according to the selected combo box values from the first form.The dynamic textboxes are displayed from jquery. Please anyone help me how to validate a dynamic text boxes on clicking the submit button. Actually I have to validate the textboxes before sending the mail. I have written a code which will validate only static textboxes. My code as below

```
<head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".myformid").click(function(){
        var nameVal = $('.names').val();
        var emailVal = $('.emails').val();
        var phoneVal = $('.phones').val();       
        if(nameVal == "")   
        {
           $('#errmsg').html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Please enter the Name</p>");      
        }   
        else if(emailVal == ""){
          //alert("A textbox is required"); 
          $('#errmsg').html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Please enter the email Id</p>"); 
        }
        else if(!ValidateEmail(emailVal))
        {
           $('#errmsg').html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Invalid Email Id</p>");  

        }
        else if(phoneVal == "")   
        {
           $('#errmsg').html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Please enter the Phone Number</p>");

        }
        else if(isNaN(phoneVal))
        {
           $('#errmsg').html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>Please enter the Valid Phone Number</p>");

        }
        else if(emailVal !="" && phoneVal != "")    
        {
           $('#errmsg').text(" ");

           var username = $('#usernameId').val();
    var length = $('#lengthId').val();    
    var nameArray = [];     
    var emailArray = [];
    var phoneArray = [];
    $('.names').each(function(){
       nameArray.push(this.value);         

    });    
    var nameboxVal = nameArray.join(",");           

    //alert(nameboxVal);     

    $('.emails').each(function(){
       emailArray.push(this.value);

    });
    var emailboxVal = emailArray.join(",");
    //alert(emailboxVal);  

    $('.phones').each(function(){
       phoneArray.push(this.value);   

    });
    var phoneboxVal = phoneArray.join(",");          

    //alert(phoneboxVal);

      $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "/invl_exams/popSubmit",   
          data: {user:username,name:nameboxVal,email:emailboxVal,phone:phoneboxVal,lengths:length},              
          success: function(result){  

            console.log(result);

            $('#mailSuccess').text('Mail Send Successfully');         
            $('#mailSuccess').fadeOut(5000);
          }

        });


        }

       });

      });

// Passing dynamic textboxes inside the dialog box
    $(".create-user").change(function(){      

        var selVal = $(this).val();         
        $('#lengthId').val(selVal);    
        $("#textboxDiv").html('');    


        if(selVal > 0) {

            for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {   

              var sno = i;               


               $("#textboxDiv").append('<tr><td>'+sno+'. </td><td>Name:<input type="text" name="names" class="names" value="" required="required" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Email:<input type="email" name="emails" class="emails" value="" required="required" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Phone:<input type="text" name="phones" class="phones" value="" required="required" minlength="10" maxlength="16"/><br/></td></tr>');         

            }                            

          }


    });  

  });


</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Enter details to send Mail">   
     <!--<form id="myformid" method="post" action="<?php //echo $this->webroot?>users/sendmail">-->
      <div id="mailSuccess" style="color:#019002;font-weight:bold"></div> 
      <form id="myformid" method="post">     
      <table id="examtable">   
        <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr> 
          <div id="textboxDiv"></div>  
          <input type="hidden" name="username" id="usernameId" value="<?php echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'); ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="length" id="lengthId" value="">                                    
        </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>        
         <!--<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">-->
        <input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Send Mail" id="popSubmit">                           
       </td>        
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any validation is happening at all, whether the elements are static or dynamic.

```
$(".myformid").click(function(){
```

will not bind to anything because there are no elements with the **class** "myformid". The "." at the start of a selector indicates a class.

However you do have an element with an **id** "myformid". If you change your selector from . to # to indicate an id, then it will bind the event to the form. However, "click" is not the correct event to bind to a `<form>` element. You want to handle the form's "submit" event:

```
$("#myformid").submit(function(event){
```

Lastly, as it stands, your form will do a regular (non-ajax) postback as well as running your function, because the default behaviour of the submit event is not suppressed. Add this  line as the first line of the above function:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This will stop a regular postback from happening and allow your validation function to execute. At that point you should have a working solution, assuming the logic in your validation code is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your validations are right you just need to attach event in way that dinamicly created elements will be supported too (jQuery on)

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

for example

from

```
$(".myformid").click(function(){/*Some action*/});
```

to

```
$("body").on('click', ".myformid", function(){/*Some action*/});
```

from

```
$(".create-user").change(function(){/*Some action*/});
```

to

```
$("body").on('change', ".create-user", function(){/*Some action*/});
```

Small advice: Try to avoid using $("body") selector you can see what is your good dom element witch is parent to your dynamically generated contend/elements.